# Java jlink read config from conf directory

Tags: java, java-web-start, jlink

As Java is stopping the support for webstart we are currently searching for another aproach. 
We come up to bundle our client-app with jlink. 
So far so good the app is running but there is a problem.

How will the client-app knows to which server it need to communicate?

We would like to add a config file to the jlink linked zip file during downloading with a downloader servlet. Similar to a JNLP Servlet

JLink-Zip looks like this.

```
/--bin
   |-- launcher   
/--conf
   | -- configfile
```

How can I get the location of this file?

I alread tried

```
Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

or

```
Main.class.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".");
```

But this will just give me the module name like /client.module

I would like to get the configfile no matter from where you will start the launcher.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely Rolf

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution.

Instead of creating an config file you can simply change the launcher.
It's nothing more than an bat or sh file.

There you can add a program parameter with the url.

Our downloader servlet  will generate such a batch file and add it to the zip file.

With this the client app can be started and will communicate over the url which was used for the download.

Greetings
Rolf